# Custom actions using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

**Background:**

The Rails 4 application I am working on has differing logic for API and web registrations, and part of this logic makes their integration extremely difficult. To that end, I'm attempting to separate the routes to deal with issues arising from inheritance, new reCAPTCHA gem, and new logic.  (both actions call `registrations#create` after their respective logic.)  I've solved most of the issues arising from separating these two; however, getting the routes working has proven difficult as well.

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

---

**Desired Result:**

I'm trying to define a route to a custom action using Devise, and prevent it from creating the default route as well.  I've gotten one of them working, but not the second.  Here's the excerpt from my routes.rb:

```
Registry::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :user,
             controllers: {
               passwords:     'users/passwords',
               sessions:      'users/sessions',
               registrations: 'users/registrations'
             }

  devise_scope :user do
    post 'users', to: 'users/registrations#custom_one'
  end

  # ...

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      # ...
      devise_scope :user do
        post 'users', to: 'registrations#custom_two'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Issues:**

The issue is that this code generates two nearly-identical routes.  Excerpt from `rake routes`:

```
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)         users/registrations#create
            users POST   /users(.:format)         users/registrations#custom_one
     api_v1_users POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)  api/v1/registrations#custom_two
```

I also want the custom route to have the correct prefix/route name (user_registration), though I've been unable to do this.

I've found plenty of documentation on custom names for Devise routes, but not for custom actions.  Especially not when using `devise_for`.

---

**To summarize:**

- I need to disable the default `users/registrations#create` route
- and specify a route to a custom action (`users/registrations#custom_one`)
- with the correct prefix/name (`user_registration`)

hopefully as elegantly as possible, as I would rather avoid specifying each route independently.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the :skip option to devise_for:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations] do
    get "/admin" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
    post "/admin" => "devise/registrations#create", :as => :user_registration
end
```

Comment: Well, this lead me to the solution.

Comment: well what we are doing here is disabling the default registrations routes of devise using skip option and creating our own I guess you should give this a try and if any error comes or any issue then as always you can comment here.

Comment: Exactly what i gave you 
`get "/admin" => "devise/registrations#new",  :as => :new_user_registration

post "/admin" => "devise/registrations#create",  :as => :user_registration

post '/users', to: 'users/registrations#custom_one'`